# What is the preferred way of matching a variable with a pattern guard that doesn't use the matched value?

Tags: rust

Between the two snippets below, which is the better / preferred one?

```rust
fn main() {
    let pair = 7;

    match pair {
        pair if pair > 5 => println!("Yeah"),
        _ => println!("No"),
    }
}
```

```rust
fn main() {
    let pair = 7;

    match pair {
        _ if pair > 5 => println!("Yeah"),
        _ => println!("No"),
    }
}
```

And is there a better way to write this? Because this doesn't work:

```rust
fn main() {
    let pair = 7;

    match pair {
        > 5 => println!("Yeah"),
        _ => println!("No"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to question, but the match arm `_ if pair > 5` can use the `6..` range pattern instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version that does not bind the matched variable is preferred:

```
fn main() {
    let pair = 7;

    match pair {
        _ if pair > 5 => println!("Yeah"),
        _ => println!("No"),
    }
}
```

This is the shortest version *with a match*. Of course, this example could just use an `if`.

<s>I'm actually surprised that the first  version does not give a warning about unused variables.</s>

Ah, this was me being silly. The variable **is** used here, in the pattern guard. ^_^

Comment: Thank you, I agree in this simple case it could. But if you add more cases, e.g. `> 1000` `> 100`  `> 10` `> 0` ... It would not be very nice with `if else if else`. Could there be any possibility to see my last example as syntactic sugar in a future version? I mean could I propose this to the devs or does it make no sense?

Comment: And why would my first example give a warning for unused variables? As I see it, pair is always equals pair, so the first pattern is always true (after that you add the guard condition)

Comment: @MathieuDavid the left hand side of the *match arm* is a pattern, and it creates a new set of *variable bindings*. Notably, the outer `pair` and the inner `pair` are different. If you changed the inner name to `foobar` and removed the guard, it would **also always match**.

Comment: @Shepmaster which variable would be counted as unused in the first example?

Comment: @MathieuDavid yeah, I figured your example was a simplified version. *Personally*, I don't think that change would be useful, but I would **strongly encourage** you to open discussion about it on the [Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/)! There may be lots of other people that would want it.

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely do that. I know it's not very useful but it removes some repetition in some cases. That's why I said syntactic sugar ;)

Comment: @Levans oh, whoops! I saw it wasn't used in the match arm body, but forgot about the pattern guard! Embarrassing!

Comment: @Shepmaster I made a [post on the Rust user forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/proposal-for-syntactic-sugar-for-match-with-some-pattern-guards/1636/1) :)